# Why does the assignment statement does not work when using "$?" at second time in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I run my scripts by bash. I found that my statement does not work when using second "RESULT=$?" command. Why?

The first varible equal "0", but why the second one is NULL ?

```
sudo pip --version
RESULT_SUDO=$?

pip --version
RESULTP_USER=$?

echo "${RESULT_SUDO}--------------"
echo "${RESULT_USER}=============="
```

Comment: Capturing the exit code is kind of pointless anyway.

Comment: @tripleee In this example, yes. Generally speaking not.

Comment: Generally speaking, too. You should almost always use the shell's flow control statements instead of explicitly examining the value of `$?`. But yes, of course, there are some situations where you do need to capture its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a typo. Try to change

```
RESULTP_USER=$?
```

to

```
RESULT_USER=$?
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: A lot of questions asked on SO are ;-)